# Is there a way to tell your hostname within a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to determine the hostname of the server you're running in w/ in a stored procedure?

You can run system hostname from a client but you can't make system calls from SP.  I don't see it any of the global variables or statuses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see my hostname on my PC

```
mysql> show variables like 'hostname';
+---------------+--------------+
| Variable_name | Value        |
+---------------+--------------+
| hostname      | LW-REDWARDS2 |
+---------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

This works in MySQL 5.x

```
SELECT variable_value INTO @local_hostname
FROM information_schema.global_variables
WHERE variable_name = 'hostname';
```

The query works directly in the mysql client:

```
mysql> SELECT variable_value INTO @local_hostname
    -> FROM information_schema.global_variables
    -> WHERE variable_name = 'hostname';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @local_hostname;
+-----------------+
| @local_hostname |
+-----------------+
| LW-REDWARDS2    |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is quick SP I wrote in MySQL 5.5.12 on my PC

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `junk`.`ShowHostName` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `junk`.`ShowHostName` ()
BEGIN

    SELECT variable_value INTO @local_hostname
    FROM information_schema.global_variables
    WHERE variable_name = 'hostname';
    SELECT @local_hostname;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then run `CALL junk.ShowHostName();`

```
mysql> CALL junk.ShowHostName();
+-----------------+
| @local_hostname |
+-----------------+
| LW-REDWARDS2    |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Here it is as a function

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `junk`.`GetHostName` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `junk`.`GetHostName` () RETURNS VARCHAR(64)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE local_hostname VARCHAR(64);

    SELECT variable_value INTO local_hostname
    FROM information_schema.global_variables
    WHERE variable_name = 'hostname';

    RETURN local_hostname;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now, just SELECT it:

```
mysql> SELECT junk.GetHostName();
+--------------------+
| junk.GetHostName() |
+--------------------+
| LW-REDWARDS2       |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: *facepalm*  I looked right over it.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select @@hostname into your_variable;
```